# How many objects does Facebook return by default?

Tags: api, facebook-graph-api

If I make the query `https://graph.facebook.com/[post_id]/comments`, how many comments does facebook return in its data array?

Similarly, what is the default number for `feed`, `likes` and other 'variable' connections?

I couldn't find documentation on this anywhere, sometimes I see a limit of 25 and sometimes I see a limit of 5000 (etc). I would be glad if someone would point me to the documentation in this case.

Answer (score 2):

If you call `https://graph.facebook.com/[post_id]/comments` with no limit it will by default return upto 25 results with paging at bottom of array.

You can override the default by using limit, since & until parameters

```
https://graph.facebook.com/[post_id]/comments?limit=250
// returns 250 results

https://graph.facebook.com/[post_id]/comments?limit=500&since=2+years+ago&until=now
// returns upto 500 posts, ranging back to 2 years ago, until right now.

https://graph.facebook.com/[post_id]/comments?since=last+week&until=yesterday
// returns upto 25 posts ranging from last week, until yesterday.
```

refer to https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/

Comment: thanks for the info @shawn, but do you know where this default of 25 results is actually documented? The link you mention is just the general documentation of the graph API.

Comment: vedang, it is just general knowledge from observation, there is not documentation.  If you make any api call it will by default return 25 results with paging at bottom of array.